# gdk.jar library file download

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, google-glass, google-gdk

I have been facing problem with gdk.jar library file add-on in sdk folder. I have tried a sample program for google glass used in android virtual devices, from which I have added a gdk.jar file in project but I don't know why that jar file was not added in sdk add-on folder.

so I get the error like:`04-12 13:16:17.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3721): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.glass.app.Card`

help me get me correct answer.

or else post the link  download the gdk.jar library file link:

advance thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the gdk.jar add-on lib file. this is  link:[download jar file](https://github.com/harrywye/gdkdemo/tree/master/apidemo/gdk/libs).

Answer (score 0):

Follow this path and information to download the Android Developer Tools (ADT).

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

You will also want to set up your development environment to use the GDK for Google Glass (see: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/

Answer (score 0):

For ADT, look for in the SDK manager under 4.4 for Glass Developer Preview.

Set your project.properties to target and

```
# Project target.
target=Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19
```