# Troubles getting up and running with GDK on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, google-glass, gdk

So I'm new to Glass and really want to build something on it.  I downloaded one of the samples and the error that Android Studio is giving me when I try to Run is `Error: Default Activity not found`.  Being extremely new to Android/Glass/Java development, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Articles Referenced:

- [Android Studio || GDK 'hello word' || import com.google.android.glass.app.Card || Cannot Resolve Symbol 'google'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695542/android-studio-gdk-hello-word-import-com-google-android-glass-app-card?rq=1)
- [Google Glass Android Studio Gradle issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23064855/google-glass-android-studio-gradle-issues?rq=1)
- [gdk.jar library file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23027754/gdk-jar-library-file-download)
- [Android Studio Gradle Configuration with name 'default' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188489/android-studio-gradle-configuration-with-name-default-not-found?rq=1)
- [Google Glass: GDK with Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107002/google-glass-gdk-with-android-studio?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

For Glass there are no Default activities however for the development purposes you can temporary add a launcher activity that you suppose will be launched by a voice command. add this line for the main Activity in the Android Manifest

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```